# merging array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

is there a way to merge the following array :

```
var arr = [["2014-2-5", "2014-2-4", "2014-1-9", "2014-1-8"], [], ["2014-2-4"], [], []]
```

and make it look like :

```
["2014-2-5", "2014-2-4", "2014-1-9", "2014-1-8", "2014-2-4"]
```

I tried `console.log($.merge(arr ));`
but it is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah definitely duplicate. Ignore my answer. use `[].concat.apply([], arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Use Array's [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in combination with [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
arr.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
  return previousValue.concat(currentValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not merge but flatten-

```
Array.prototype.flatten= function(){
    var A= [];
    this.forEach(function(itm){
        if(itm!= undefined){
            if(!itm.flatten) A.push(itm);
            else A= A.concat(itm.flatten());
        }
    });
    return A;
}

var arr= [["2014-2-5", "2014-2-4", "2014-1-9", 
"2014-1-8"], [], ["2014-2-4"], [], []];
arr.flatten();

// returned value: (Array)
['2014-2-5', '2014-2-4', '2014-1-9', '2014-1-8', '2014-2-4']
```